# How to return values from autoit script to selenium

Tags: selenium, autoit

How to return values from autoit script to selenium?

I want to return string value from autoit to selenium

```
String t = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\AutoItScipts\\downloadWindow.exe");
System.out.println(t);
```

Thanks,

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the InputStream of the process:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your autoIT exe file path");

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

And then, method `waitFor()` will make the current thread to wait until the external program finishes and returns the exit value.

```
int exitVal = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
```

And in your AutoIT script, you have to probably write output to the console (please try):

```
ConsoleWrite("data")
```